# Show linear transformation is not one-to-one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

$$T(x, y, z) =  \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
x - 2z \\
-3x + y + 3z \\
x - y + z\end{array} \right]$$

I've taken the matrix of coefficients:

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&-2 \\ -3&1&3 \\ 1&-1&1 \end{bmatrix}$

And reduced it to row-echelon form as follows:

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&2 \\ 0&1&3 \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$

But, I'm not sure where to go from here in proving that this transformation is not one-to-one.

I understand that a one-to-one transformation has a pivot in every column, but I'm not sure what this means and how it applies to this matrix.

Where can I go from here in proving this?

Comment: An immediate criterion is that the matrix $A$ has rank $2$ although it is of order $3$, so it cannot be invertible, which means the endomorphism described by it is neither injective nor surjective (since if it were one it would also be the other). A more concrete answer would be to notice that the image of the endomorphism described by this matrix is isomorphic to the subspace of vectors whose last coordinate is null, at any rate a proper subspace. This tells you that the image itself is a proper subspace, and thus your endomorphism is not surjective.

Comment: Your row reduction shows that he vectors $(0,0,0)$ and $(-2,-3,1)$ both map to $(0,0,0)$, so it is not injective.

Comment: I think you lost a minus sign or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, instead, obtain the reduced $A$ as:

$$A' = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &0& -2 \\ 0&1&-3\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

From the reduced $A$, we notice that a general solution to $A\vec x = \vec 0$ is given by:

$$\vec x = \begin{bmatrix} 2t\\3t \\t\end{bmatrix}$$

We also see that $A \begin{bmatrix} x\\y \\z\end{bmatrix} = T(x,y, z)$.

Hence we obtain $T(2t,3t, t) = \vec0$ for any $t$.

This shows that $T$ is not injective.

In fact, the null space is $\left\langle\begin{bmatrix} 2\\3 \\1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the determinant (of the original matrix).  You get zero.

Or, the RREF has rank two.  Thus by the Rank-Nullity theorem, the nullity is one.

Answer (score 0):

$-2$ first column $-3$ second column is the third column. This shows that the dimension of the image is inferior or equal to $2$.

Answer (score 0):

A theorem presented in a linear algebra course states that a linear transformation $T$ is one to one iff $\ker(T)=0$. Now, the nullspace of this matrix, upon solving the appropriate equation, turns out to be a line, so it follows that the linear transformation represented by this matrix isn't one to one.